# Can I easily change the colour of text output to the Windows Console from a C Program

Tags: c, command-line, colors

I want to make some printf's to the windows console from my C program but want to make some of them different colours.

Anyone know if this can be done easily?

EDIT: Windows XP is my OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SetConsoleTextAttribute()` will let you set the color of subsequent text output.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686047.aspx

You'll probably want to look at the complete set of Win32 console APIs to be able to get/set/restore and otherwise manipulate the console.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682073.aspx

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible in CMD (correct me if I'm wrong). You can only change the foreground and background color of CMD as a whole. Not by line, or word.

For changing its foreground and background colors please refer to the `color` command:

`color /?`