# Colored Text Windows Command Line

Tags: c, windows, terminal, colors, console

Recently I'm messing around with colors in the terminal.

I'm using a sample program from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) to test this out in different consoles.

In the `Windows Terminal` from the Microsoft Store, you can see colors:

[image: colors]

Below is the exact same program, but in `cmd.exe` in which you can't see the colors.

[image: No colors]

In the same exact console however, when I run the command `gcc` I do get additional colors (white and red, in fact):

[image: gcc]

Now my question is, what does `gcc` do differently, to still be able to print colored text? I can't find any other way to get colored text on the console than written on the linked site above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question can help you:

- [Color console in ANSI C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274824/color-console-in-ansi-c?rq=3)
- [Can I easily change the colour of text output to the Windows Console from a C Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822310/can-i-easily-change-the-colour-of-text-output-to-the-windows-console-from-a-c-pr?rq=3)
- [C color text in terminal applications in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9203362/c-color-text-in-terminal-applications-in-windows?rq=3)

This is the list for functions you needed (in this example we use red in green):

- For printing one or more character: use [`GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolescreenbufferinfo) and pass the `lpConsoleScreenBufferInfo->dwCursorPosition` to [`WriteConsoleOutputAttribute()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsoleoutputattribute) and then use the [`WriteConsoleOutputCharacter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsoleoutputcharacter) with the same length passed to `nLength`.
  Code:

```
    HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO consoleBuffer;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo (hStdOut, &consoleBuffer);
    const char *string = "AABBCCDDEEFFGG";
    int length = strlen(string);
    DWORD written;
    WriteConsoleOutputAttribute(hStdOut, (WORD*)(FOREGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_GREEN), length, consoleBuffer.dwCursorPosition, &written);
    WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(hStdOut, string, length, consoleBuffer.dwCursorPosition, &written);
```

- For entire console: [`system("color 0F")`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3822360) or use [`GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolescreenbufferinfo) and pass the `lpConsoleScreenBufferInfo->dwCursorPosition` to [`SetConsoleTextAttribute()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoletextattribute) function.
  Code for `SetConsoleTextAttribute()`:

```
    HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO consoleBuffer;
    const char* string = "AABBCCDDEEFFGG";
    int length = strlen(string);
    DWORD written;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hStdOut, &consoleBuffer);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hStdOut, FOREGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_GREEN);
    WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(hStdOut, string, length, consoleBuffer.dwCursorPosition, &written);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hStdOut, FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_RED | 0);
```

**Note: You can use [`WriteConsole()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsole) instead of using `WriteConsoleOutputCharacter()` function.
Don't forget to restore the mode!**

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`SetConsoleTextAttribute()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoletextattribute) API