# C++ Windows Terminal Colorization doesn't work for stdout redirect

Tags: c++, windows, cmd, windows-terminal

I have the following issue. I want to colorize text in my Windows Console.
I am required to load the console as follows:

```cpp
AllocConsole();
freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout); // redirect stdout
```

Afterwards I can print some text with the usual

```cpp
std::cout << "hi!\n";
```

Doing `SetConsoleTextAttribute` using the Windows API (as explained in [Colored Text Windows Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69865250/colored-text-windows-command-line)) like this

```
SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 0);
std::cout << "0\n";
SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 1);
std::cout << "1\n";
```

just results in the entire output being colored after the last `SetConsoleTextAttribute` statement (in this case `1 -> blue`).

I have also tried writing ANSI colors (https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/5255355/How-to-Put-Color-on-Windows-console)

```cpp
std::cout << "\033[32mgreen\033[0m\n";
```

however, that resulted in `←[32mgreen←[0m` (on `cmd.exe`, it works correctly for the new and shiny Windows Terminal `wt.exe`).

Both approaches didn't work. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this issue? I think the redirect `freopen(...)` is causing trouble, however I couldn't make a lot of sense out of the Windows API documentation.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: It's not clear what isn't working about the `SetConsoleTextAttribute` version.  Are you saying that text written before the first `SetConsoleTextAttribute` call has its color changed as well?  That seems unlikely because the documentation specifically says "Changing a screen buffer's attributes does not affect the display of characters previously written"

Comment: Yes, the entire output, independent of its position (prior or post the `SetConsoleTextAttribute`) is changed to the color of the last `SetConsoleTextAttribute` statement.

Comment: Does `std::flush` have any effect?  `\n` normally causes a flush but... worth trying

Comment: It'd be `std::endl` instead of chaining `flush` to a linebreak

Comment: Yes, thanks for the help! Flushing the stream using `std::endl` solved the issue.

Comment: There are in general two source code design options depending on which versions of Windows your program should work: __1.__ There are used the classic [Console Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions) which work on any 32-bit and 64-bit Windows. __2.__ There is used the modern [Console API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/using-the-console) with [Console Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) limiting the program usage to newer versions of Windows 10 and Win 11.

Comment: It is advisable to start the research for your console application development with [Welcome to the Windows Console documentation!](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/) and read first the general information pages listed on left side from top to bottom for getting the required knowledge for further decisions on the route to use for your console application development. Reading the Microsoft documentations would at least help to understand why your code failed and why the usage of `std::endl` helped to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding:

> however, that resulted in `←[32mgreen←[0m` (on `cmd.exe`, it works correctly for the new and shiny Windows Terminal `wt.exe`).

This is due to the fact that the Windows Terminal enables virtual terminal processing by default, while the vintage console (`conhost.exe`) does not.

To get those sequences to work in conhost, you need to enable virtual terminal processing. You can do this by calling `SetConsoleMode` with the `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING` flag.